# In Angular I need to delete item from my view page but not from Firebase database. Any suggestions for this?

Tags: angular, firebase, crud

This is my delete function in `component.ts` file:

```
delete() {
  this.firebaseService.deleteUser(this.item.id)
  .then(
    res => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
}
```

This is my service file function

```
deleteUser(userKey) {
  return this.db.collection('users').doc(userKey).delete();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide that for a while? since data will get bind dynamically. What you can do is to take a 'status' field in your DB and set it to 0 (deactive) and 1 for (active). So, while fetching records you need to display those records which have status 1 and on delete change status to 0.

Comment: @Mridul I got it. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also delete data from array based on id when user clicks on delete click button. reference [StackBlitz Link is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjvwup). Here, array.splice() is useful and according to that removed array you can do further more operations based on filtering data.

```
data  = [
   {id:1, name:'pencil'},
   {id:2,name:'pen'},
   {id:3, name:'stationary'}
]

delete(id,index){
   this.removeObjectIs = this.data.splice(index,1);
}
```

and Template file is...

```
<table class="table table-dark">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">Action</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of data index as i"> 
            <th scope="row">{{data.id}}</th>
               <td>{{data.name}}</td>
               <td style="text-align:center; color:brown; cursor:pointer" >
                    <i (click)="delete(data.id,i)" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="removeObjectIs.length >= 1"> Removed ID is : {{removeObjectIs |json}}</div>
```

Comment: I'll check this array.splice() method. thank you @Gaurang